# OAuth 2.0 username-password flow: Is the access token long lived?

Tags: oauth2, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I am a newbie to Salesforce. I am planning on implementing username-password OAuth 2.0 flow in my iOS app. I am getting **access_token** after calling *`https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`* API. Is this token long lived? It seems there is no way to refresh this access_token. Can I use this in future without having to refresh it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the operation response and handle any exception. If the response is an 401 containing this JSON:

```
[ { message: 'Session expired or invalid'
  , errorCode: 'INVALID_SESSION_ID'
  }
]
```

, you could call a refresh_token flow like this :

[image]

**However**, you only get the refresh token from the Web server and User-Agent as is indicated [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm).

> If the application uses the username-password OAuth authentication
>   flow, no refresh token is issued, as the user cannot authorize the
>   application in this flow. If the access token expires, the application
>   using username-password OAuth flow must re-authenticate the user.

So, I think that after login using user-password flow, **you should re-authenticate the user or change the flow.**

**Refresh Token**

> The refresh token may have an indefinite lifetime, persisting until
>   explicitly revoked by the end-user. The client application can store
>   the refresh token, using it to periodically obtain fresh access
>   tokens, but should be careful to protect it against unauthorized
>   access, since, like a password, it can be repeatedly used to gain
>   access to the resource server. Since refresh tokens may expire or by
>   revoked by the user outside the control of the client application, the
>   client must handle failure to obtain an access token, typically by
>   replaying the protocol from the start.

I recommend you to read this article of [digging deeper into OAuth in force](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com)

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the answer to my question is ***"If the access token expires, the application using username-password OAuth flow must re-authenticate the user."*** Right? To re-authenticate I have to call *https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token* API again? Please let me know.

Comment: Exactly that is the answer

Answer (score 0):

The session timeout for an access token can be configured in Salesforce by logging into the account your app is configured with, and going here:

`Setup | Administer | Security Controls | Session Settings`

which was detailed on [this page](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm)

You also need to make sure that your application is configured to give out a `refresh_token`, which is specified:

- in `Selected OAuth Scopes` with a value of `Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)`, and can be found in your account under `Setup | Build | Create | Apps`

[Info on Refresh Tokens at Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Token_Refresh)

Note that your app has to send the request correctly as well. Passing the correct `scope` is required to get a `refresh_token` back, and [valid scopes are detailed on this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Configuring_OAuth_2.0_Access_for_your_Application)